# current time matches between two different times

Tags: sql

I have a start time and end time and also the current time.

```
starttime = '3/4/2014 9:01:00.483 PM'
endtime   = '3/5/2014 5:01:00.483 AM'

currenttime = '1:10AM';
```

My issue is I have to check whether the `currenttime` is between the start and end time.

Is it possible to do in a SQL query? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `WHERE currenttime BETWEEN starttime and endtime`?

Comment: Along with the RDBMS, what are the data types of starttime, endtime and currenttime?